# How do salts of a weak acid + weak base behave in solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, solubility

Say you have Ammonium Formate in solution, the salt formed by the reaction of Formic Acid and Ammonia.  Would both the Formate ion and Ammonium ion protonate and deprotonate, respectively, to form their conjugates until equilibrium is reached?  I would also assume that one of the ions would form more of their conjugate than the other depending on which ion in the pair is a stronger acid/base.  My question arose when researching the Leuckart reaction, which wikipedia states that if ammonium formate is used, it dissociates to formic acid and ammonia before participating in the reaction.  I also found it peculiar that ammonium formate is listed as soluble in diethyl ether, which typically doesnt dissolve salts.  This behavior would make more sense if ammonium formate dissociated into formic acid and ammonia.

Comment: Long story short, yes, they hydrolyze, sometimes completely.